# Derivative of function between open sets

Tags: derivatives, continuity, manifolds

Consider a function $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$, where $A$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}$. Because an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ does not enjoy the property of being a vector space, the above function is "non-linear". The derivative of it, however, can be defined as the linear function that approximates it *most closely*, namely

$\dfrac{\Delta f_a(t)}{t}\to f^\prime(a)$ ($t\to 0$), where $\Delta_af(t):=f(a+t)-f(a)$.

Now I understand that the open set is a metric space, and the target set of $f$ being a vector space, is also a normed space, so the notion of continuity is perfectly well defined.

What I don't understand in the above definition is how could we define $f(a+t)$ as the domain isn't a vector space, and hence addition ($a+t$) makes no sense! (maybe via some one-parameter group of transformations?).
Furthermore, if I consider some other function, $g:C \to D$, from an open set to an open set, then the target space not being a vector space, I cannot write down $g(a+t)-g(a)$ to define $\Delta g_a(t)$. So how does one define the derivative of such a $g$?

Comment: If $A$ is open and $a\in A$ then there exist $r>0$ such that $(a-r,a+r)\subset A.$ So, if $t<r$ $f(a+t)$ is well defined.

Comment: You are discovering the concept of *tangent space* in differential geometry.

Comment: @mfl Is this the reason why in the definitions of derivatives and continuity we use the notion of open sets?

Comment: Yes. But on  a closed set you can define lateral derivatives.

Comment: @mfl Care to elaborate a bit?

Comment: Consider $f(x)$ defined on $[a,b]$. Then you can define $f'(a^+)=\lim_{x\to a^+}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.$

Comment: The set of natural numbers is not a vector space. Does 2+3 make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is an open set, for all $a\in A$, there exists $r>0$ such that:
$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}\textrm{ s.t. }|x-a|<r\}\subseteq A.$$
Therefore, for $t<r$ one has $|a+t-a|<r$ and $a+t\in A$. Whence the well-definedness of $f'(a)$.

Regarding the second part of your question, the codomain of the function does not matter, it is not required that $g(a+t)-g(a)\in D$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, why is it not required that $g(a+t) - g(a) \in D$?

Comment: The expression $g(a+t)-g(a)$ may not be in $D$, but it still makes sense in $\mathbb{R}$, which is sufficient.

Comment: Is this related to the fact that we can always free a vector space over any set? Namely I can always extend D to $\mathbb{R}$?